# use of Scrapy's regular expressions

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I'm practicing on scraping newspaper's articles with Scrapy. I have some problems in sub-stringing text from web pages. Witht the built-in `re` and `re_first` functions I can set where to start the search, but I don't find how to set **where to end**.
Here follows the code:

```
import scrapy 
from spider.items import Articles 
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "lastampa"
    allowed_domains = ['lastampa.it']

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
                'http://www.lastampa.it/2017/10/26/economia/lavoro/datalogic-cerca-laureati-e-laureandi-per-la-ricerca-e-sviluppo-rPsS8gVM5ZX7gEZcugklwJ/pagina.html'
                ]

        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):

        items = []

        item = Articles()
        item['date'] = response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "ls-articoloDataPubblicazione")]').re_first(r'content=\s*(.*)')
        item['author'] = response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "ls-articoloAutore")]').re_first(r'">\s*(.*)')
        item['title'] = response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "ls-articoloTitolo")]').re_first(r'<h3>\s*(.*)')
        item['subtitle'] = response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "ls-articoloCatenaccio")]').re_first(r'">\s*(.*)')
        item['text'] = response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "ls-articoloTesto")]').re_first(r'<p>\s*(.*)')
        items.append(item)
```

Well, with this code I can get the needed text, but also all the following tags till the end of paths.
e.g.

```
'subtitle': 'Gli inserimenti saranno in Italia, Stati Uniti, Cina, Vietnam</div>'
```

How can I escape the ending `</div>` (or any other character after a defined point) ?
Can someone can turn on the light on this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to mess with regular expressions like this if you only need to extract the text from elements. Just use `text()` in your XPath expressions. For example for `subtitle` field, extract it using:

```
item['subtitle'] = response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "ls-articoloCatenaccio")]/text()').extract_first().strip()
```

which, in your example, will produce:

```
u'Gli inserimenti saranno in Italia, Stati Uniti, Cina, Vietnam'
```

Article `text` is a bit more complicated, as it's spread over child elements. However, you can extract it from there, post-process it and store as a single string like this:

```
item['text'] = ''.join([x.strip() for x in response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "ls-articoloTesto")]//text()').extract()])
```

which will produce:

```
u'Datalogic, leader mondiale nelle tecnologie di identificazione automatica dei dati e dei processi di automazione industriale, ha lanciato la selezione di giovani talenti laureati o laureandi in ingegneria e/o in altre materie scientifiche che abbiano voglia di confrontarsi con una realt\xe0 internazionale. Il primo step delle selezioni si \xe8 tenuto in occasione dell\u2019Open Day: i candidati hanno sostenuto un primo colloquio con senior manager nazionali e internazionali, arrivati per l\u2019occasione anche da sedi estere. Durante l\u2019Open Day \xe8 stata presentata l\u2019azienda insieme alle 80 posizioni aperte di cui una cinquantina in Italia. La ricerca dei candidati \xe8 rivolta a laureandi e neolaureati di tutta Italia interessati a far parte di una realt\xe0 dinamica e internazionale, provenienti da Facolt\xe0 tecnico-scientifiche quali Ingegneria, Fisica, Informatica.Ai giovani verr\xe0 proposto un interessante percorso di carriera che permetter\xe0 di approfondire e sviluppare tecnologie all\u2019avanguardia nei 10 centri di Ricerca dell\u2019azienda dislocati tra Italia, Stati Uniti, Cina e Vietnam, dove si ha l\u2019opportunit\xe0 di approfondire tutte le tematiche relative all\u2019elettronica e al software design: dallo sviluppo di sistemi operativi mobili, di sensori laser e tecnologie ottiche, allo studio di sistemi di intelligenza artificiale. Informazioni sul sito www.datalogic.com.Alcuni diritti riservati.'
```